# Gorm find subset in HasMany

Tags: search, grails, grails-orm, subset

I have the following relation in which I want to search

```
class Order {
    static hasMany = [articles:Article]
}
class Article {
}
```

In my search I select N articles and I want to find all Orders that contain all the N selected articles. So far I was only able to find all Orders that contain one of the selected Articles.  It would be great if anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order.executeQuery("select o from Order o join o.articles as a where a in (:articleList)", [articleList: articleList])
```

Comment: "All N selected articles in Order". Wouldn't the above pass for at least 1 article? I think it should be join of N queries?

Comment: Please explain how you got to your answer and not just give it so that others with similar but different problems may learn too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but dmahapatro is right, I need a query to find all N selected articles in Order and not to find all Orders that contain at least one of the selected articles. Any ideas?